# PHP/MYSQL while loop shorted

Tags: while-loop

I have next php code:

```
$nr = 1;
$baza1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10");
$rand = mysql_fetch_array($baza);
while($rand = mysql_fetch_array($baza)) 
{
echo $nr." | ".$rand['rezultat'];
$nr++;
}
```

This code return me the output:

```
NR | RESULT
1. | Result 1
2. | Result 2
3. | Result 3
4. | Result 4
5. | Result 5
6. | Result 6
7. | Result 7
8. | Result 8
9. | Result 9
10.| Result 10
```

I want to return me first 5 rows then break then result with no. 10, something like this:

```
NR | RESULT
1. | Result 1
2. | Result 2
3. | Result 3
4. | Result 4
5. | Result 5
.. | ..
10.| Result 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that retrieving the top 10 results in your SQL query is the correct approach, despite that you only want to show certain of this result set.  In my answer below, I added logic to conditionally print only records 1-5 and 10.

```
$nr = 1;
$baza1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10");
$rand = mysql_fetch_array($baza);
while($rand = mysql_fetch_array($baza)) {
    if ($nr <= 5 || $nr == 10) {
        echo $nr." | ".$rand['rezultat'];
    }
    else if ($nr == 6) {
        echo ".. | ..";
    }
    $nr++;
}
```